# How to find line segments intersecting a 2D viewport

Tags: geometry

In an infinite 2D space there are a set of lines, each line having a start and end point, and a time of creation: `Line(p0, p1, t)`.

I want to find the lines that should be rendered in a top-down view of this 2D space (higher values of t show up closer to the viewport, not that it should be relevant.)

The intuitive answer is "check if either point is within the viewport coordinates," but this falls down when the points are further apart than the viewport area covers.

The other idea I had was using something like [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), this would limit precision i.e. maximum zoom level of the viewport. The idea is enumerating the hashes of the cells intersected and storing them. This way querying is a matter of asking the right question.

Are there any ideal solutions? Has this been solved before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check two conditions: one that the rectangle of viewport overlaps the rectangle with corners (p0,p1) and the second that some corners of viewport rectangle are on the different sides of the whole line which contains line segment (p0,p1).

The task of finding rectangle overlap can be solved very effectively for very large number of rectangles using R-trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

The second task can be reduced to  checking signs of the cross product of (p1-p0) x (corner_coordinate-p0) 
(all three quantities taken as 3-d vectors with third coordinate equal to zero, the result will be vector along the perpendicular direction). There should be corners with the opposite sign of this cross product.

Comment: Ok, an R-tree it is. Do you know of a R-tree reference implementation in MongoDB? MongoDB has built-in spatial indexing, could it be appropriated for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `corner_coordinate` signifies, the viewport has at least two corners as it is a rectangle. If I interpret it as the south west corner being (0,0) and `corner_coordinate` being the north east corner, it doesn't make sense!

Comment: Consider a line p0 = (-2, -1); p1 = (7, 4) and a viewport from (0, 0) to c = (3, 2). `(p1 - p0) x (c - p0) = (7 + 2, 4 + 1) x (3 + 2, 2 + 1) = (9, 5) x (5, 3) = 2`. This is correct as the line intersects the viewport rectangle, but consider then instead p1 = (5, 5) which also intersects the viewport: `(p1-p0)x(c-p0)=-9`!?

Comment: I mean you need to check all 4 corners of the viewport, and find if all the corners give the same sign to the cross product (in which case line does not intersect viewport) or some corners give the different signs. Sorry if this was not clear.